# Subir datos de temperatura a una base de datos SQL

Tags: php, mysql, python, raspberry-pi

¡Hola!

Tengo un pequeño proyecto de subir datos de temperatura a una base de datos desde una raspberry pi 3.

He visto varios tutoriales, pero ninguno me ha funcionado hasta ahorita o las librerías que descargo no funcionan. ¿Qué debo hacer para poder empezar?

Saludos y que tengan muy buen día

Edit: Solamente me gustaría poder ser capaz de mandar datos desde mi RPi hacia la base de datos, donde tenga una 3 columnas con estos nombres: Fecha, hora y temperatura.

El código para leer los datos de temperatura lo tengo yo, también los de fecha y hora... sin embargo, no sé cómo empezar, qué necesito descargar y qué procedimiento tengo que hacer para subir esos datos de temperatura a la base de datos. He intentado descargar el apache y el php con este comando:

sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5

Sin embargo, me sale un error de que no se pudieron conseguir ciertos archivos.

"Unable to fetch some archives. Maybe run apt-get update or try with - -fix-missing?

PD: Gracias por la recomendación, Kenny

Comment: Eduardo, bienvenido a SOes. Tu pregunta es en parte buena, pero es demasiado amplia, porque se podrían hacer infinidad de cosas para empezar. Te invito a [edit] tu pregunta y poner que has intentado y porque no ha funcionado. Saludos!

Comment: Necesitamos que nos expliques un poco mas tu pregunta, ya que es demasiado amplia para responder ( pon algo de código ), explica donde tienes problemas.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que no tengo nada de código ni librerías. Literalmente no sé nada de cómo empezar a montar una base de datos ni de lo que necesito. Lo único que tengo de código funcional es la lectura de los datos de temperatura, hora y fecha.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo en tu pregunta muestras que estas intentando levantar el servidor web en el mismo rasberri, pero lo que quieres es enviarlo a un servidor web en otra computadora, entonces lo que yo te recomiendo es que investigues: como levantar un servidor web, si estas usando python para tu programa como hacer un POST a un servidor web desde python, y por ultimo como manejar un RAW POST en php [o un POST normal]

Comment: Aqui tienes un mini-tutorial para hacerlo,  http://librosweb.es/libro/python/capitulo_12.html

Answer (score 1):

Para solucionar el error que te da al instalar el apache, como bien dice el error, primero deberías actualizar tu sistema:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Para enviar los datos depende desde que lenguaje quieras hacerlo. [Aquí](https://www.marksanborn.net/howto/sending-post-data-with-curl/) te dejo un tutorial muy simple de como hacerlo desde la línea de comandos (con curl) y recibir los datos desde un PHP.

Espero que te sirva.